# How to convert python datetime to MariaDB

Tags: python, datetime

How to convert python datetime `2022-03-28T11:59:22.559+0300` to MariaDB datetime as
`2022-03-28 11:59:22.559` ?

Comment: [`time.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime) along with [`time.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime), depending on whether you're dealing with a `datetime` object or just a string.

Comment: @MattDMo [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library might offer more convenient features. Also, it seems the OP could just strip the UTC offset and replace T with space in given example.